# 'Bus error' when trying to start VSCode via WSL2 Ubuntu

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, bus-error

I recently (tried to) set up my windows laptop for data science. Installed WSL2 with Ubuntu, VSCode, Jupyter and Anaconda. Everything worked fine.

Today, about a week later, I tried to access a jupyter notebook I had started in vscode via the following steps:

- open terminal
- open a tab for Ubuntu
- then:

```
~ via  base … 
➜ cd DataScience
    
~/DataScience via  base … 
➜ cd ProjectFolder
    
~/DataScience/ProjectFolder via  base … 
➜ code . 
Bus error
```

And instead of starting VSCode, I get "Bus error". That's all. Googling the problem didn't really help me. Apparently, some link/address is not correct? Or memory that is not existent is tried to be accessed?
In the windows-terminal, I checked if WSL2 needed an update, but seems to be up to date.

I have no background in CS and don't get at all why this is not working anymore.
Can anybody explain and help me fixing this, please?